# Annoying padding between tmux bar and bottom of terminal window when maximised

Tags: tmux, gnome-terminal

I am using tmux inside of a gnome-terminal.

When I first open a window (with the default size being 80x24) the tmux bar sits snugly at the bottom of the window. When I maximise the terminal window, however, an annoyingly large gap appears underneath the tmux bar.

[maximised gnome-terminal tmux session with gap under tmux bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1qJf.png)

This is my .tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g default-command bash

# remap prefix to Control + a
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix
bind-key C-a-h split-window -h #Split panes vertically

# time/no(0) time between C-a and command
set -s escape-time 0

#set-option -u repeat-time #global setting, "delete" repeat-time

set-option -g -q mouse on #activate mouse
```

How do I get the tmux bar to sit as it does in the small this when I maximise the terminal window?

[80x24 gnome-terminal window with tmux bar located correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFYz0.png)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You will have to adjust your font size. The gap is introduced since the height of terminal window is not exactly N-lines high. If you really hate that gap, you may either enlarge or shrink your font size until you find one that fits your screen.